# How update React state in useEffect hooks with socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flask-socketio

I am a newbie for React, using Typescript React for my project. I am trying to use `Socket.IO-client` to connect to my Socket.IO flask server.

***My server would only emit the newest info e.g. 1st emit: item 1, 2nd emit: item 2...***

And my React UI would show the details of the previous and latest info.
I have put the codes of data fetching in the useEffect hook.
However, it suggests that

> *React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchedData'. Either >include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional >update 'setFetchedData(f => ...)' if you only need 'fetchedData' in the >'setFetchedData' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*

I don't think that I  can put fetchedData in the dependency array as fetchedData is constantly updating, which would cause an infinite loop. Is there any way I can do it? Your help is deeply appreciated.

```
const MyPage = () => {
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] =  useState<string[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('get_list', { user : 'userId');

        socket.on('response', (list:any) => {
            fetchedData.push(list.data)
            setFetchedData([...fetchedData])
        })
    }, [])

    return(
        {
            fetchedData.map(value, index) => <div key={index}>{value}</div>
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: You're not allowed to do `fetchedData.push(list.data)`, i.e. mutate state directly. As for the warning, did you try the functional update?

Comment: Thank you. It works. I change it to `setFetchedData(prevData => [prevData, list.data])`.

Comment: @CccAv the above change you made might have some unwanted side effects. You're better off using the spread operator to create a new array e.g. `[...prevData, ...list.data]` If `prevData` has deeply nested objects / arrays this will still not be sufficient as it's not truly immutable. Same goes for `list.data`

Answer (score 0):

See here **https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-socket.io-client**

UseSocket hook for react

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues you are facing that I'll try to address.

**Missing dependencies in `useEffect`.**

This is caused by an eslint rule from the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) package, it is included in Create react app by default.

The rule in question is `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` and it usually finds it's way into my `.eslint.rc` set to `off` for the reason you see above. Most of the time it's quite safe to add all the dependencies though I typically find that the list grows out of proportion and I really only want to see a list of dependencies that the `useEffect` really cares about having changed.

You rightly state you don't want it as a dependency. Either ignore the rule for the specific line, or if you feel you understand how the deps work fully turn the rule off in your eslint rc file.

Alternatively, you can ensure that your hook dependencies are declared without errors. This would require you to abstract the callbacks to your `socket.on` call into their own `useCallback` hooks that have their own dependencies. I won't give any more info on this as you can try it out if you wish and then ask another question if you run into issues.

**State mutation**

As others have mentioned, you need to be careful not to mutate your state. You won't have a type error as you don't define your state type as readonly. Try changing:

`<string[]>useState(...)` to `<readonly string[]>useState(...)` and you'll see that you're calling mutating functions directly on your state.

Comment: I don't think turning off warnings is the best way to approach this (or anything). The warning text mentions a functional update, which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @ChrisG Actually that rule specifically has a huge amount of conversation around it for this reason. I agree that turning rules off is generally not a good way to go but for this one, when you really only want your useEffect to be called just the once with `[]` the rule makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update `fetchedData` using `setFetchedData`

```
socket.on('response', (list:any) => {
   setFetchedData([...fetchedData,list.data])
})
```

Comment: True, but has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: I know, but OP is asking about useEffect dependicies in combination with socket.io statements. The fact that they're illegally mutating state is irrelevant.